# Argument type does not conform to expected type

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want a generic `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` that can do its thing based on two generic parameters, like so:

```
protocol ItemDisplaying where Self: UIViewController {
  associatedtype T

  var item: T { get }

  init(item: T)
}

final class LinearPageDataSource<V: ItemDisplaying> {
  let items: [V.T]

  init(items: [V.T]) {}
}
```

However, a method within the data source like this:

```
private func indexOf(_ viewController: V) -> Int {
  return items.firstIndex(of: viewController.item) ?? NSNotFound
}
```

Errors out with `Argument of type V.T does not conform to expected type 'Equatable'`.
Therefore, I added explicitly this code: `class OnboardingContentViewController<T: Codable & Equatable>: UIViewController, ItemDisplaying` so I can show that the type of the item passed in as `T` in the ViewController is `Codable & Equatable`.

I'm getting stuck in what I'm trying to achieve, I'd like to have a data source that takes an array of items that are at least `Codable & Equatable` and I'd like to keep a generic possibility for a type of `UIViewController` to be passed in. How can I best achieve this?

Comment: Can you not apply the `Codable & Equatable` constraints to the `associatedtype`? Like so: `associatedtype T: Codable & Equatable`. Or is this not what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelFourre That’s what I’m trying to do, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @MichaelFourre If I add that conformance to associatedtype, I'll get errors in the UIViewController saying Equatable can only be used as a generic constraint, because it has Self or associated type requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that an `associatedtype` can't refer to another protocol, but has to refer to a concrete type. Therefore the following works:

```
protocol ItemDisplaying where Self: UIViewController {
  associatedtype T: Decodable & Equatable

  var item: T { get }

  init(item: T)
}
```

```
final class LinearPageDataSource<V: ItemDisplaying>: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
  let items: [V.T]

  init(items: [V.T]) {
    self.items = items
  }

  func contentViewController(atIndex index: Int) -> V? {
    return V.init(item: items[index])
  }
```

```
final class OnboardingContentViewController: UIViewController, ItemDisplaying {
  typealias T = OnboardingItem // this is a struct, conforming to Decodable and Equatable

  let item: T

  required init(item: T) {
    self.item = item
  }
}
```